# Regex to extract particular attribute and innerHTML of a div inside contentEditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

## Background

---

I am creating a `@Name` Tagging system for my webpage. and I've succeeded in finding names on keystroke and replace the content with equivalent `div class='tag' data-id='User-id'>Name</div>`(at least for displaying). Now before submitting those contents from `contentEditable` div. I modify them in a `textarea` (which is usually hidden).

## Working

---

As soon as `.keyup` event occurs on `contentEditable` all the contents of `contentEditable` are processed by function `MakeItForWeb(contentEditable)`. Which then Manipulates the contents of `textarea` which will be processed by server side `php` script. that `php` script will strip all the tags and then store data in DB. so before submitting I try to replace all the `.tag` div with following format of data:

```
@["id":"User-id","Tag":"User-Name"];
```

In `<textarea>`, I have created a `regular expression` in `javascript` to achieve the task. and it is working fine, when there is single `.tag` in single line, You can see it [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qGHjx/1/).

## Problem

---

When More than 1 `.tag` occurs in a single line then My `regex` fails to recognize all of them correctly, and recognize only last of them. And thus whole tagging system crashes, You can see it [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qGHjx/2/). May be My approach is wrong. Can Experts here help me out please? any suggestion is welcome.

## My Efforts(Code)

---

`JavaScript + JQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").attr("spellcheck","false");
    $("#tarea").keyup(function(e){ // Process KeyUp Event
         /* Code to find Names on @N..and create a tag is omitted purposefully as it is working fine */ 
        // Make each tag Un-editable, So that User cant change it
        $(".tag").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("contentEditable","false");
        });
       //Manipulate the textarea with equivalent value
       MakeItForWeb(this);
    }).focus(function(){
       //Manipulate the textarea with equivalent value from contentEditable
        MakeItForWeb(this);
    });
    $("#tarea").trigger("keyup"); // Trigger keyUp event as soon as DOM ready.
});
function MakeItForWeb(x){
    var htm=$(x).html(); // Contents of contentEditable
    htm=htm.split("<br>").join("\n"); // Replace <br> with \n character
    htm=htm.split("&nbsp;").join(" "); 
    htm=htm.trim(); // Trim contents
    /* Here is My regex which does the mentioned task */
    htm=htm.replace(/<div(.*) data-id=\"(.*)\" (.*)>(.*)<\/div>/g,"@['id':'$2','tag':'$4'];");
    document.getElementById("opc").value=htm; // <textarea> = ContentEditable processed.
}
```

---

Note the Line:

```
htm=htm.replace(/<div(.*) data-id=\"(.*)\" (.*)>(.*)<\/div>/g,"@['id':'$2','tag':'$4'];");
// This is My Regex.
// where var htm=contentEditable.innerHTML;
```

---

`HTML`:

```
<div id="tarea" contentEditable="true" class="tarea" autocorrect="false" spellCheck="off">
    Hello Says! <div class="tag" data-id="1005">Vedant Terkar</div> , <br />To all <div class="tag" data-id="1006">SO Users</div>&nbsp; :-).
</div>
<!-- This textarea is Usually Hidden -->
<textarea id="opc" rows="5" cols="97">
</textarea>
```

`css` is irrelevant to problem, so not posting it.

Hope experts here will help me out. Thanks in advance :-) !

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: same as in previous fiddle without newline. like: `Hello Says! @['id':'1005','tag':'Vedant Terkar']; , To all @['id':'1006','tag':'SO Users'];  :-).`.

Answer (score 1):

Get the matched group from index 1 and 2. I used *Lazy* way.

```
<div class="tag" data-id=\"([^\"]*?)\">([^<>]*?)<\/div>
```

here is online [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aS1dS2/1)

---

Try this one to get the "Hello Says!" and "To all" as well in 3 catapulting groups.

```
>\s*([^<>]*)<div class="tag" data-id=\"([^\"]*?)\">([^<>]*?)<\/div>
```

here is online [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aS1dS2/2)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, But both of them doesn't work for me see `<textarea>` from output of http://jsfiddle.net/qGHjx/3/  and http://jsfiddle.net/qGHjx/4/, and what i expect is http://jsfiddle.net/qGHjx/1/

Comment: put a new line in replacement string in the end. Sorry I don't have any idea about JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks I have little knowledge about regex that I can tell you but not about JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
<div\b.*?\bdata-id=\"([^"]*)\">([^<]*).*?\/>([^<]*)<div\b.*?\bdata-id=\"([^"]*)\">([^<]*).*
```

Replacement string:

```
@['id':'$1','tag':'$2']; , $3@['id':'$4','tag':'$5'];
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vK3xN1/1)

Comment: It isn't working. see: `<textarea>` from output of http://jsfiddle.net/qGHjx/5. still +1 for helping :-) and your efforts!